# how to write a class for login user in php

Tags: php, authentication

I write this function in class login:

```
function loginUser($mobile,$pas){   
    $pasw = hash_value($pas);
    $sql1 = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` WHERE (`mobile`=:mobile AND `pas`=:pas)");
    $sql1->execute(array(
    ":mobile"=>$mobile,
    ":pas"=>$pasw
    ));
    $num = $sql1->fetchColumn();
    if($num==1){
        echo 'login successfully';
        }else{
        echo 'Error';
          }     
    }
```

And then write this code in check.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['mobile'])&&isset($_POST['pas'])){
   $mobile = Check_Post($_POST['mobile']);
   $pas = Check_Post($_POST['pas']);
   $login = new Login();
   $res= $login->loginUser($mobile,$pas);
}
```

But when I enter the correct mobile and password in the login form, the code returns an error in my screen.

Comment: How is `hash_value` defined? If you are doing hashing properly then hashes should not be directly comparable.

Comment: @Chris the function of hash_value is :                                                                     function hash_value($value){
  return md5($value)."!@DSFS@##%$#@#";
 }